# ASA >> Switch >> Server WAN/LAN Routing to NIC ports

Tags: local-area-network, cisco-asa, nic, ifconfig

I bought a Dell R610 to setup VMware ESXi -- the server has 2X dual port NICs.  Normally with a single dual port NIC I assign my WAN IPs to eth0 and LAN IPs to eth1.

With the new server I'd like to route my WAN IPs to eth0:x, eth1:x, eth2:x, & eth3:x, AND route  switch derived LAN IPs (192.168.0.x) to the NIC interfaces as well.

Basically I'd like to VPN into my Cisco ASA 5505 and SSH into 192.168.0.x and "arrive" at an ESXi virtual machine instance.

Not sure if this is possible, limited networking experience here.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wire up each pNIC to one or two switches, set them as trunks and expose the appropriate VLANs up them, then you can a single resilient vSwitch0 and create port groups for each VLAN - assigning them to VMs and the Management Console as you wish.

Comment: thanks

setup is:
uplink >> firewall >> switch >> 2 servers (ESXi & a backup server)

ASA will route /27 IP block through switch to the 2 servers. I know how to set a dual port NIC in bare metal setup (ex. WAN IP to eth0 and LAN IP to eth1), but not to ESXi on 2X dual port NICs where I want ethX to receive BOTH WAN & LAN IP ranges (so I can access ESXi VMs on ethX via WAN or LAN IP)

I guess I could dedicate 2 ports to WAN and 2 ports to LAN, but that's not ideal, would much prefer 4 WAN/LAN port groups to use for devel & prod VMs...